# Connecting Compute Engine instances with storage and databases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-networking

I am building my data processing platform on Google Cloud and I need advice on how to everything together for speed optimization. I am running two Compute Engine instances where I do data processing and one separate instance where I serve MongoDB database. I also have Google Cloud Storage and maybe in the future some BiQuery or other things. I will be sending a lot of data across instances and databases and I am wondering if it is possible to speed data transfer since they are all Google Cloud products? I am new to this stuff and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use internal IPs only for any inter-component communication within the GC platform. That way data will not leave Google's internal network and transfer will be very fast.

Comment: Good answer. Also keep the instances in the same zone to maximize network performance. For autoscaling and load balancing, use the same region to keep network latencies to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing Google Cloud Network performance, please keep in mind those 5 steps:

1. Use networking performance tools: lperf, Netperf, traceroute
2. Put VM Instances  in correct zones - close to each other.
3. [Chose right vCPU with corresponding network speed](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#egress_throughput_caps).
4. Use internal IP, not the external ones - using Google own network will be faster
5. Resize TCP window

For more details about [Google Cloud Network Performance please refer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml).

---